# C++ sleep without using the sleep function

Tags: c++, animation

so long story short am going through several images in a loop so it'll appear the image is being animated, however, the animation would be insanely quick, I want to make it just a tad bit slower. I tried using Sleep() however, that makes my entire program sleep for the specified seconds, making it seems like it is in slow mo. Is there any other way to do this?

Below is my code

```
 if (left == true)
    {
        if (m_state == 0)
        {
            Sleep(25);
            image1 = ImageManager::loadImage("running-1.png", true);
            image1.renderImageWithMask(m_pEngine->getForegroundSurface(), 0, 0, m_iCurrentScreenX, m_iCurrentScreenY, 170, 200);
            m_state += 1;
        }
        else if (m_state == 1)
        {
            Sleep(25);
            image1 = ImageManager::loadImage("running-2.png", true);
            image1.renderImageWithMask(m_pEngine->getForegroundSurface(), 0, 0, m_iCurrentScreenX, m_iCurrentScreenY, 170, 200);
            m_state += 1;
        }
        else if (m_state == 2)
        {
            Sleep(25);
            image1 = ImageManager::loadImage("running-3.png", true);
            image1.renderImageWithMask(m_pEngine->getForegroundSurface(), 0, 0, m_iCurrentScreenX, m_iCurrentScreenY, 170, 200);
            m_state += 1;
        }
        else if (m_state == 3)
        {
            Sleep(25);
            image1 = ImageManager::loadImage("running-4.png", true);
            image1.renderImageWithMask(m_pEngine->getForegroundSurface(), 0, 0, m_iCurrentScreenX, m_iCurrentScreenY, 170, 200);
            m_state += 1;
        }
        else if (m_state == 4)
        {
            Sleep(25);
            image1 = ImageManager::loadImage("running-5.png", true);
            image1.renderImageWithMask(m_pEngine->getForegroundSurface(), 0, 0, m_iCurrentScreenX, m_iCurrentScreenY, 170, 200);
            m_state += 1;
        }
        else if (m_state == 5)
        {
            Sleep(25);
            image1 = ImageManager::loadImage("running-6.png", true);
            image1.renderImageWithMask(m_pEngine->getForegroundSurface(), 0, 0, m_iCurrentScreenX, m_iCurrentScreenY, 170, 200);
            m_state = 0;
        }
```

Comment: [`std::this_thread::sleep_for()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) using some appropriately-small duration not working for some reason?

Comment: there is no "sleep without sleep". What you are actaully looking for seems to be multithreading. Its a wide topic, too much to be introduced in an answer here, and too little information given in the quesiton to provide a simple answer

Comment: What OS or framework are you using? Can you use OS- or framework-level events and a message/event loop?

Comment: On another note, why not use an array for the file-names, or construct them when needed, and you don't need all your `if else if else if etc.`. Your approach will be hard to scale if you add more images.

Comment: In Windows, you'd add a timer event then wait for WM_TIMER messages to tell you when  to flip to the next image.

Comment: All user interface frameworks have a concept called a "timer" such that your function/code will be invoked on a periodic interval so you do animation type stuff.  If you can tell us what platform (OS, language, and framework), we can tell you what to do.

Comment: @DaveS `WM_TIMER` is a low-resolution, low-priority timer that is not a good choice for game animation. Consider a [multimedia timer](https://learn.microsoft.co/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/multimedia-timers) or other high-resolution timer instead. Or, even just let the game loop run normally and don't render the next image until X iterations have passed or X time has elapsed.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

...

std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds(10) );
```

You can also use nanoseconds, if that's what you want.

Comment: thanks, a lot, a lot, but it behaved similarly to sleep, which pauses the whole program by that amount of time. Rather, I was looking for it just so that it doesn't load the image instantly. Right now, I'm loading these images in a loop over and over and they instantly load so they're changing their state really really fast as if like an animation but speed up 100x times, rather than slowing down/ pausing the program entirely by a specified time I was wondering if there's a specific thing I can do so these images would load in at a slower times while the program is still running smoothly

Comment: @P47HF1ND3R Why don't you load all required images beforehand then? Surely loading them every time, while it seems fast, is a slow operation. So any attempt to sleep is going to get your timing off

Comment: OP doesn't need to sleep. OP needs to read the current time and compute `m_state` based on the current time in milliseconds

Comment: I figured out my own problem, I'm using a framework to develop this, and in the drawing function, it is reloaded every second, so everything is reloaded, at least in the foreground/background so, instead of making it draw every second and delaying it, I Moved it to a separate function/method and slow that down so even if it's reloading every second it's not being drawn, but the last drawn image is still displayed hence making it animated. The comments above arent useful at all but to their credit I weren't super clear as well but thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my own problem, I'm using a framework to develop this, and in the drawing function, it is reloaded every second, so everything is reloaded, at least in the foreground/background so, instead of making it draw every second and delaying it, I Moved it to a separate function/method and slow that down so even if it's reloading every second it's not being drawn, but the last drawn image is still displayed hence making it animated.

```
   if (!isVisible() || getEngine()->isPaused())
        return;
    image1.renderImageWithMask(m_pEngine->getForegroundSurface(), 0, 0, m_iCurrentScreenX, m_iCurrentScreenY, 170, 200);
```

this is my drawing function from the framework, and instead of making it draw different pictures every second, I pass in an image loading function so the image will be drawn and kept on the screen every second and not reloaded

and below it, I have a delayed animation function (its really a delayed loading picture  function, but since the whole screen is redrawn I just delay the new image to be loaded giving it an animated appearance )

```
if (counter >= 10)
    {
        if (left == true)
        {

            if (m_state == 0)
            {
                image1 = ImageManager::loadImage("f_running-1.png", true);

                m_state += 1;
            }
          counter = 0;
        }
    }
    counter += 1;
```